# How to handle Windows file browse window using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

How to handle file window popup using selenium webdriver.

I have clicked on file browse button , new pop up window has been opened and i am unabled to handle this window(as i want to select the file)

```
 WebElement browser=driver.findElement(By.name("uploadFile"));
browser.click();
driver.switchTo().window("File Upload");
WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.name("fileName"));
el.sendKeys("E:\\DVBScheduleEvent.xml");
```

Comment: Don't click the upload button. Just do `driver.findElement(By.name("uploadFile")).sendKeys("E:\\DVBScheduleEvent.xml");`

Answer (score 3):

I have a sample code for this:

```
driver.get("http://www.2shared.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("upField")).sendKeys("D:\\james.xls");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Upload file']")).click();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Method for file handling:

We need :

jacob.jar  [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)

It will contain one jar file and 2 .dll files

AutoItX4Java.jar  [Download](https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/downloads/detail?name=AutoItX4Java.jar&can=2&q=)

```
public static void uploadFile(String path, String browser){

    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

        if(x.winWaitActive("Open", "", 10)){
            if(x.winExists("Open")){
                x.sleep(500);
                x.send(path);
                x.controlClick("Open", "", "Button2");

            }
        }

    }


    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

        if(x.winWaitActive("File Upload", "", 10)){
            if(x.winExists("File Upload")){
                x.sleep(500);
                x.send(path);
                x.controlClick("File Upload", "", "Button2");

            }
        }
    }

    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer")){

        if(x.winWaitActive("Choose File to Upload", "", 10)){
            if(x.winExists("Choose File to Upload")){
                x.sleep(500);
                x.send(path);
                x.controlClick("Choose File to Upload", "", "Button2");

            }
        }
    }



}


   public void test(){
       //Click on the Select button of the file upload
       uploadFile("Path", "chrome");


   }
```

Thanks... Dont click Accept or Upvote until it works for you. If it is not working for you means, please comment.. Dont Downvote...

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```php
WebElement filepath=driver.findElement(By.id("fileUploadId"));
filepath.sendKeys("C:\\TextFile.txt");
```