# strange Selenium2 No Such Element error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML code.

```
`<div> <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
    <span>                                  
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="uploadFile" value="Attach2" id="1309261001000145" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;top:0;left:0">  <input type="button" onclick="fireFileButton('1309261001000145')" value="Attach" name="input"  class="btn_grn btn_sm">
    </span>                                         
 </div>`
```

the div is in a normal nested divs. The second  is the displayed 'attach file', once clicked, the "fireFileButton" function will click the first  form(which is hidden on top left 0,0 position). then a pop up window appear as the type is 'file' to select file to upload and an ajax to upload.

I'm to use Selenium2 to simulate the file upload process. 
I use the following codes:

```
 WebElement attach = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("//input[name^='input']")));
 attach.click();
 WebElement upload = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("1309261001000145")));
 upload.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");
```

I also tried directly use sendKeys Function on first  element. But have the error of NO SUCH ELEMENT both for first and second . I have used By.id,name,cssSelector,xpath but to no avail.

the elements can be selected using javascript.

Any Suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
By.cssSelector("//input[name^='input']")
```

Selectors should not contain `//`,so replace the above with :

```
By.cssSelector("input[name='input']")
```

[You can refer this to know more about Selectors.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html)

Comment: thanks, but i think it's not this kind of grammar mistake. I've tried select by id, name, xpath, all to no avail. I even tried to select by js using executeScript, but still can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

First check : ID tag.

It seems that ID for the input buttons are dynamic. So we cant access through the ID's.

Second check : NAME tag.

We can use, since it has a name for it.

```
WebElement attach = driver.findElement(By.Name("input"));

attach.click();
```

If it is not clicking, use Actions.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.moveToElement(attach).click().perform();
```

You cannot pass the values directly using sendkeys for file upload.

Check this page for my solution in order to access with file upload : [How to handle Windows file browse window using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116392/how-to-handle-windows-file-browse-window-using-selenium-webdriver/21601149#21601149)

Comment: thanks for sharing . but if the element cant be found, attach would be null. I finally solve the problem by execute a piece of javascript code.