# How to select many files using Windows file explorer with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, webdriver

I am automating a UI test where selecting file to upload is involved, I was able to automate the file selection using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989124/5077196).

```
WebElement filepath=driver.findElement(By.id("fileUploadId"));
filepath.sendKeys("C:\\TextFile.txt");
```

My issue is that I need to select many files to upload, is there a special format I should follow in the path I am sending? because I tried space-separated paths and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *upload multiple files* you can construct the *character string* adding all the *absolute path* of the files seperated by `\n` as follows:

```
WebElement filepath = driver.findElement(By.id("fileUploadId"));
filepath.sendKeys("C:/TextFile1.txt \n C:/TextFile2.txt \n C:/TextFile3.txt");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed documentations in:

- [How to upload multiple files using SendKeys Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071064/7429447)
- [How to upload multiple files to a website using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65312679/7429447)