# How to upload multiple files using SendKeys Selenium

Tags: selenium, file, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, sendkeys

I have an element with following HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" value="[]" id="upload1" class="upload">
```

To the best of my understanding its value is an array/list and it's supposed to store uploaded files paths (multiple files are allowed).

I use following code to upload ONE file:

```
.FindElementById("upload1").SendKeys ("C:\file1.txt")
```

and it works just fine. However, i need to upload multiple files but I do not get how to populate the array with multiple filepaths using `SendKeys`.

I use vba to automated data entry from within excel.

Comment: Are you sure? If input field doesn't have boolean `@multiple` then it probably doesn't support uploading multiple files at the time

Answer (score 6):

To *upload multiple files* you can construct the *character string* adding all the *absolute path* of the files seperated by `\n` as follows:

```
.FindElementById("upload1").SendKeys("C:/TextFile1.txt \n C:/TextFile2.txt \n C:/TextFile3.txt");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to upload multiple files to a website using Python and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65312679/7429447)
- [How to select many files using Windows file explorer with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869603/7429447)

Comment: Hii, this is not working for some reason, I even tried like this `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: File not found: file:///C:/Users/amel.islamovic_bbm/Desktop/projects/twitter-bot/results/haber/1711027971111124992.png \n file:///C:/Users/amel.islamovic_bbm/Desktop/projects/twitter-bot/results/haber/1711027975989207040.png`, any help?