# Sauce Labs not treating "\n" as an escape sequence within sendKeys method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, escaping, saucelabs

In Saucelabs when I'm executing a method with Selenium:

```
element.sendKeys("C:/file1.txt\nC:/file2.txt");
```

Saucelabs is not treating `\n` as an escape sequence/newline character, it works while importing only one document, but while running using sauce labs it takes those two files as a whole string and ignoring `\n`. I tried `\\n` and many other similar characters.

P.S. The same approach works perfectly while running locally, sendKeys can send multiple files separated by `\n`

I expect Saucelabs to identify multiple files in a string separated by `\n`

Comment: Try your OS newline: `\r\n` for Windows or `\r` for MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

The filenames and the filename seperator, i.e. `\n` needs to be seperated by a space character as follows:

```
element.sendKeys("C:/file1.txt \n C:/file2.txt");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to upload multiple files using SendKeys Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071064/7429447)
- [How to select many files using Windows file explorer with selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869603/7429447)