# Uploading an entire folder in Selenium (Chrome)

Tags: selenium

Is it possible to simulate drag and drop of an entire folder into a browser dropzone in Selenium?

I know that we can upload individual files by setting the value attribute of `input[type="file"]` to the file path. But when I try with a folder path, it seems that the browser is treating it as a file. Since there is no extension (because it's a folder), the upload fails.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is impossible.
You can not upload entire folder by this way.
You will have to iterate over all the files in that folder and upload them one by one sending their full absolute paths to that `input[type="file"]` element.
**UPD**
You can upload multiple files by constructing the character string adding all the absolute path of the files separated by `\n` as follows:

```
WebElement filepath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
filepath.sendKeys("C:/TextFile1.txt \n C:/TextFile2.txt \n C:/TextFile3.txt");
```

Credits to [DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869603/3485434)

Comment: you can send multiple file paths by sending keys to the <input type="file"> element.  Use "\n" to separate them.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866662/how-to-select-many-files-using-windows-file-explorer-with-selenium-webdriver/50869603#50869603

Comment: Thanks a lot! Updating the answer.

Comment: This is what I thought. Unfortunately, I need to upload the entire folder for this test (because I want to verify that the folder structure is respected in the app, post-upload). So the "\n" trick will not save me.

Comment: @Rybos This is what we can do with Selenium. I see no better options. If you find - please let me know.

Comment: It might be possible to do this using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) to read each file in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

All files in the folder can be transferred. see below code.

```html
<div id="images_upload">
    <div class="col-12 form-group mb-3">
        <input type="file" multiple="true" webkitdirectory="true" name="data"
               directory="true" id="folderUpload" accept="image/*" class="image-flag">
    </div>
</div>
```

(Click `input tag`'s parent `div tag` instead of `input tag`.)

```py
selenium = WebDriver()

# upload button click
selenium.find_element(By.ID, 'images_upload').click()

# choose upload folder
target = selenium.find_element(By.ID, "folderUpload")
folder_abs_path = '/datasets/static/test_datasets/images')
target.send_keys(folder_abs_path)
```