# Uploading file from Windows file dialog using Python

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am writing a script to automate chatting Facebook messenger using python and Selenium WebDriver, I want to send an image however upon clicking the attach image button windows file dialog pops out. Is there any way to control windows file dialog to select the image I want?

This is the pop up window

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you looked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116392/how-to-handle-windows-file-browse-window-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Try to always display pictures (use `!` before the picture) but don't insert code or error messages as pictures.